# Understanding the Codes of Tello Drone

Tags: python

I am a beginner learning to program a drone, called Tello. I have got these codes online. They are working with the drone.

Here are the codes of `tello.py` file:

```
# This code is adopted from https://learn.droneblocks.io/p/tello-drone-programming-with-python/
# Import the necessary modules
import socket
import threading
import time


class Tello():

    def __init__(self):
        # IP and port of Tello
        self.tello_address = ('192.168.10.1', 8889)

        # IP and port of local computer
        self.local_address = ('', 9000)

        # Create a UDP connection that we'll send the command to
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        # Bind to the local address and port
        self.sock.bind(self.local_address)

        # Create and start a listening thread that runs in the background
        # This utilizes our receive functions and will continuously monitor for incoming messages
        self.receiveThread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        self.receiveThread.daemon = True
        self.receiveThread.start()

    # Send the message to Tello and allow for a delay in seconds
    def send(self, message, delay):
        # Try to send the message otherwise print the exception
        try:
            self.sock.sendto(message.encode(), self.tello_address)
            print("Sending message: " + message)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error sending: " + str(e))

        # Delay for a user-defined period of time
        time.sleep(delay)

    # Receive the message from Tello
    def receive(self):
        # Continuously loop and listen for incoming messages
        while True:
            # Try to receive the message otherwise print the exception
            try:
                response, ip_address = self.sock.recvfrom(128)
                print("Received message: " + response.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
            except Exception as e:
                # If there's an error close the socket and break out of the loop
                self.sock.close()
                print("Error receiving: " + str(e))
            break
```

Here are the codes of `flight1.py` file:

```
import tello

# Billy
billy = tello.Tello()

# Each leg of the box will be 100 cm. Tello uses cm units by default.
box_leg_distance = 100

# Yaw 90 degrees
yaw_angle = 90

# Yaw clockwise (right)
yaw_direction = "ccw"

# Put Tello into command mode
billy.send("command", 3)


# Send the takeoff command
billy.send("takeoff", 5)

# Fly box pattern
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)

# Special : Flip backwards
billy.send("flip b ", 4)

# Send the land command
billy.send("land ", 4)



# Print message
print("Mission completed successfully!")

# Close the socket
billy.sock.close()
```

I can't understand the functionality of these codes. What are they doing here?

```
# Fly box pattern
    billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
    billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
    billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
    billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
    billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
    billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
    billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
    billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
    billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
    billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
```

What does "Fly Box Pattern" mean here?

I think that `billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)` will make the drone to make forward pitch. Am I right?

I can't understand the `box_leg_distance`. What does box leg mean?

Also, how can I code to make the drone reverse pitch?

Comment: Simply if you used drone before. so you should keep pressing the button 5 time to take off ! so he repeat the command ! by `billy.send("takeoff", 5)` and then sending the command while it's in command mode

Comment: There is no controller for the drone in our lab! Only the codes are given to us.

Comment: Also, I think `billy.send("takeoff", 5)` means that the "takeoff" message will be sent to Tello Drone and there will be a delay of 5 seconds. Please refer these codes in tello.py file: `def send(self, message, delay):`

Comment: alright , the code is putting the drone on command listening mode and then he send the cmd each 5 second to let it take off according to the cm

Comment: you are correct

Comment: I have asked some questions in the questions, like 'What does "Fly Box Pattern" mean here?'. Would you please answer the questions? It will be highly appreciated.

Comment: https://dronekit-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: move 90 ccw each 4 second .. check https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/ccw.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi and welcome to Python coding!

> What does "Fly Box Pattern" mean here?

The wording here is wrong. What the author actually meant is "Fly in a square shape". You can see that the drone is instructed to fly forward, rotate 90 degrees counter-clock-wise (short `ccw`) and repeat those two steps a few times. If you imagine a square in the air, the drone will essentially fly from one corner of it to the next.

> I think that billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4) will make the drone to make forward pitch. Am I right?

Not just that. The drone will pitch forward and then pitch back to neutral position once it has travelled the given distance. That said, you can not control the pitch directly, only the direction and distance of flight. Here's the relevant part of the documentation:

[image]
You can find the full documentation at [https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/2d4dce68897a46b19fc717f3576b7c6a/Tello%20编程相关/For%20Tello/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf](https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/2d4dce68897a46b19fc717f3576b7c6a/Tello%20%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3/For%20Tello/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf).

I found the link on the manufacturer's website: https://www.ryzerobotics.com/tello/downloads

There is also a possible confusion with the variables here, so let me explain the code.

```py
box_leg_distance = 100
...
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
```

In the first line a variable is defined and assigned the value `100`. The second line does two things:

1. It creates a new string out of `"forward "` and the string representation (short `str`) of the number `100`. We need to convert the number to a string because the language here thinks of things as different types. You can't really put a word and a number together, because there is no rule for that. But if you tell it to think of the number as just a word made of digits, then adding those two words means to put them after another. So `"forward " + str(box_leg_distance)` will result in the string `forward 100`. This is a valid command the drone will understand.
2. This string with the command is then sent to the drone using the function `billy.send()`. There is also a second parameter to the function, saying how many seconds to do nothing (we say "sleep") once the command has been sent. The function `send` is defined in your first file.

The whole line can be written simply like this with the same effect:

```
billy.send("forward 100", 4)
```

> I can't understand the box_leg_distance. What does box leg mean?

This poorly chosen variable name sets the distance you want the drone to fly forward each time. Going back to our imaginary square, this is the length of the square in centimeters. I know it's centimeters because the documentation linked above says so.

> Also, how can I code to make the drone reverse pitch?

As mentioned before, you can not control the pitch directly. But if you mean you want the drone to fly backwards, that can be done. If you look at the manual linked above, it mentions the `back` command. So you could write the following to make the drone fly 100cm backwards (and then stay there for 4 seconds):

```
billy.send("back 100", 4)
```

Comment: It's an amazing answer. You have explained in a very detailed way.

Comment: So, `box_leg_distance = 100` means that the drone will fly from one corner to another corner in a square whose distance is 100 cm. Am I right?

Comment: Also, how can I code to make the drone roll left and right? I mean, how can I make the drone fly to the left direction and the right direction?

Comment: Yeah, the number 100 is the distance the drone will fly each time. And since it rotates 90 degrees each time it flew, this effectively means it flies in a square that is 100 cm long and 100 cm wide.

Comment: To make the drone go left and right you have two options: either rotate it and make it go forward. Or make it fly sideways. You already know how to do the first. The latter can be achieved by sending the drone `left 100` or `right 100` commands. You can find these and more commands in the manual I linked.

Comment: Thanks for your amazing answers. I have an issue. I need to capture an image with the drone. I need to do it by using Python codes. But in the manual, there is no option for taking pictures. https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/2d4dce68897a46b19fc717f3576b7c6a/Tello%20%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3/For%20Tello/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf   What should I do? Should I post a new question on Stackoverflow regarding the issue?

Comment: Good question. I don't know. I'd ask that as a new question. This way it's going to be much easier for others to find and answer.

Comment: I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260746/tello-edu-drone-how-to-capture-image-with-python-codes

Comment: Hi, I am facing a problem. The drone is not landing on the landing pad after flying the squared path. I have posted a new question about it. Would you please take a look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59296579/tello-drone-not-landing-on-landing-pad-after-following-a-squared-path

Comment: By the way, I haven't got any solution for capturing image with the Tello Edu drone. I posted a question yesterday about it. But I haven't got any answer. What should I do? Should I contact Tello support team? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59260746/tello-edu-drone-how-to-capture-image-with-python-codes