# Tello Edu Drone: How to Capture Image with Python Codes

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, dji-sdk

I am a beginner learning to program a drone, called Tello. I am trying to capture an image with it.

I have got [the manual](https://terra-1-g.djicdn.com/2d4dce68897a46b19fc717f3576b7c6a/Tello%20%E7%BC%96%E7%A8%8B%E7%9B%B8%E5%85%B3/For%20Tello/Tello%20SDK%20Documentation%20EN_1.3_1122.pdf).

In the manual, there is no option for capturing image with the drone. Only recording video is mentioned there. How can I capture the image with Python codes with the drone?

Here are the codes of `tello.py` file:

```
# This code is adopted from https://learn.droneblocks.io/p/tello-drone-programming-with-python/
# Import the necessary modules
import socket
import threading
import time


class Tello():

    def __init__(self):
        # IP and port of Tello
        self.tello_address = ('192.168.10.1', 8889)

        # IP and port of local computer
        self.local_address = ('', 9000)

        # Create a UDP connection that we'll send the command to
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        # Bind to the local address and port
        self.sock.bind(self.local_address)

        # Create and start a listening thread that runs in the background
        # This utilizes our receive functions and will continuously monitor for incoming messages
        self.receiveThread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        self.receiveThread.daemon = True
        self.receiveThread.start()

    # Send the message to Tello and allow for a delay in seconds
    def send(self, message, delay):
        # Try to send the message otherwise print the exception
        try:
            self.sock.sendto(message.encode(), self.tello_address)
            print("Sending message: " + message)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error sending: " + str(e))

        # Delay for a user-defined period of time
        time.sleep(delay)

    # Receive the message from Tello
    def receive(self):
        # Continuously loop and listen for incoming messages
        while True:
            # Try to receive the message otherwise print the exception
            try:
                response, ip_address = self.sock.recvfrom(128)
                print("Received message: " + response.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
            except Exception as e:
                # If there's an error close the socket and break out of the loop
                self.sock.close()
                print("Error receiving: " + str(e))
            break
```

Here are the codes of `flight1.py` file:

```
import tello

# Billy
billy = tello.Tello()

# Each leg of the box will be 100 cm. Tello uses cm units by default.
box_leg_distance = 100

# Yaw 90 degrees
yaw_angle = 90

# Yaw clockwise (right)
yaw_direction = "ccw"

# Put Tello into command mode
billy.send("command", 3)


# Send the takeoff command
billy.send("takeoff", 5)

# Fly box pattern
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)

# Special : Flip backwards
billy.send("flip b ", 4)

# Send the land command
billy.send("land ", 4)



# Print message
print("Mission completed successfully!")

# Close the socket
billy.sock.close()
```

What should I do to capture an image with the drone?