# Tello Drone Not Landing on Landing Pad After Following a Squared Path

Tags: python

I am a beginner learning to program a drone, called Tello. I have developed codes that allow the drone to take off from the landing pad and fly through a squared path. However, I am facing an issue. The drone doesn't land on the landing pad. It lands a bit forward, like 80 - 100 cm.

Here are the codes of `tello.py` file:

```
# This code is adopted from https://learn.droneblocks.io/p/tello-drone-programming-with-python/
# Import the necessary modules
import socket
import threading
import time


class Tello():

    def __init__(self):
        # IP and port of Tello
        self.tello_address = ('192.168.10.1', 8889)

        # IP and port of local computer
        self.local_address = ('', 9000)

        # Create a UDP connection that we'll send the command to
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

        # Bind to the local address and port
        self.sock.bind(self.local_address)

        # Create and start a listening thread that runs in the background
        # This utilizes our receive functions and will continuously monitor for incoming messages
        self.receiveThread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive)
        self.receiveThread.daemon = True
        self.receiveThread.start()

    # Send the message to Tello and allow for a delay in seconds
    def send(self, message, delay):
        # Try to send the message otherwise print the exception
        try:
            self.sock.sendto(message.encode(), self.tello_address)
            print("Sending message: " + message)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error sending: " + str(e))

        # Delay for a user-defined period of time
        time.sleep(delay)

    # Receive the message from Tello
    def receive(self):
        # Continuously loop and listen for incoming messages
        while True:
            # Try to receive the message otherwise print the exception
            try:
                response, ip_address = self.sock.recvfrom(128)
                print("Received message: " + response.decode(encoding='utf-8'))
            except Exception as e:
                # If there's an error close the socket and break out of the loop
                self.sock.close()
                print("Error receiving: " + str(e))
            break
```

Here are the codes of `CustomFlight.py` file:

```
import tello

# Billy
billy = tello.Tello()

# Each leg of the box will be 100 cm. Tello uses cm units by default.
box_leg_distance = 100

# Yaw 90 degrees
yaw_angle = 90

# Yaw clockwise (right)
yaw_direction = "ccw"

# Put Tello into command mode
billy.send("command", 3)


# Send the takeoff command
billy.send("takeoff", 5)

# Fly in the squared path
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)

# Send the land command
billy.send("land ", 4)

# Print message
print("Mission completed successfully!")

# Close the socket
billy.sock.close()
```

Is there any problem with the codes of `# Fly in the squared path`?

The drone is supposed to take off from the landing pad and land on the landing pad. But it doesn't land there.

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how many times your drone goes forward and rotates. It's doing it five times. Therefore your drone is flying in a square and then another length of the square forward.

Just remove one of these blocks:

```
billy.send("forward " + str(box_leg_distance), 4)
billy.send("ccw " + str(yaw_angle), 3)
```

Comment: OK. I will try these codes in the lab and will get back to you.

Comment: One thing. If I want to just fly the drone for five seconds only, will I have to simply use these codes: `billy.send("takeoff", 5) billy.send("land ", 4)`. I am asking this question, as I might have to make the drone take off, capture a picture and land on the pad.

Comment: The numbers mean how many seconds to stand still and do nothing. If the drone is supposed to fly 5 seconds in total, do not use any waiting, i.e. set it to 0.

Comment: I have posted a new question regarding recording the video with the drone. Would you please take a look at it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59350980/tello-drone-how-to-record-and-save-a-video